# Papa Rudin theorem $1.36$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

**There is the theorem:**

> Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $\mathfrak{M}^*$ be the collection of all $E \subset X$ for which there exist sets $A$ and $B \in \mathfrak{M}$ such that $A \subset E \subset B$ and $\mu(B-A) = 0$, and define $\mu(E) = \mu(A)$ in this situation. Then $\mathfrak{M}^*$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathfrak{M}^*$.

**There is the proof:**

We begin by checking that $\mu$ is well defined for every $E$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M$*.

Suppose $A$ $\subset$ $E$ $\subset$ $B$,$A_1$ $\subset$ $E$ $\subset$ $B_1$, and $\mu(B-A)$ $=$$\mu(B_1-A_1)$ $=$ $0$

Since $A-A_1$ $\subset$ $E-A_1$ $\subset$ $B_1$ $-$ $A_1$

We have $\mu(A-A_1)$ $=$ $0$, hence $\mu(A)$ $=$ $\mu(A\cap A_1)$.

I really don't understand why is $\mu(A)$ equal of $\mu(A\cap A_1)$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because $A\cap A_1$ and $A \setminus A_1$ is a partition of $A$, it follows from additivity of $\mu$.

Comment: @Theorem I am also on my way to learning MT so it's better if you write hints in comment or give a brief solution.

Comment: @Math_Buddy A measure is defined to satisfy $\mu(\bigcup_n E_n) = \sum_n \mu(E_n)$ for disjoint measurable $E_n$s. This means we must have $\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus A_1) + \mu (A \cap A_1)$, and you can plug in $0$.

Comment: Ah Silly me!!! Thank You!!!

Comment: Thank you man @Theorem